# CNN vs fully connected network for image recognition?

Tags: neural-networks

Does anyone know how the accuracy of CNNs compare with fully connected networks for image recognition? Also are CNNs good at anything other than image recognition? I couldn't find anything on Google, a link or explanation would be good.

Comment: Very impressive with these newest developments for image processing by neural networks. Significant progress has been made since the state-of-the-art 15 years ago, see [M. Egmont-Petersen, D. de Ridder, and H. Handels. Image processsing with neural networks - a review, Pattern Recognition 35 (10): 2279 - 2301 (2002)]

Answer (score 4):

Fully connected neural networks are good enough classifiers, however they **aren't good for feature extraction**. Before the emergence on CNNs the state-of-the-art was to extract explicit features from images and then classify these features.

CNNs are trained to **identify and extract the best features** from the images for the problem at hand. That is their main strength. The latter layers of a CNN are fully connected because of their strength as a classifier. So these two architectures aren't competing though as you may think as CNNs incorporate FC layers.

If your question was how well a FC-based image recognition technique fairs compared to a CNN one, you should check the results of the ILSVRC for the past years. The last non-CNN architecture I think achieved a top 5 error rate of 30% (today with the state-of-the-art CNNs this is under 3%).

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know how the accuracy of CNNs compare with fully connected
>   networks for image recognition?

The sole fact that since AlexNet won ImageNet competition, every neural network that wins it uses CNN component, should be enough to convince you that CNNs are better for image data.

You most likely won't be able to find any meaningful comparison, since CNNs are able to handle image data that is infeasible using only FC layers.

Why?

- The number of weights in FC layer with 1000 neurons for 224x224x3 image is something like 150M. **That's 150M for only one layer**.
- If you're not convinced this is a huge number, then note that modern CNN architectures that have 50-100 layers while having overall couple dozen milion parameters (for example ResNet50 has 23M params, InceptionV3 has 21M parameters).

> Also are CNNs good at anything other than image recognition?

Yes. They're good for any data that has spatial structure (for example 1D convolutions over time for music).

Also they're used in NLP - see [this paper on sentiment analysis](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C14-1008) or [this one on translation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.10099.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

**1. Computational tractability.**
number of weights between CNN and FC such as
input image of shape 500 x 500 x 3 will be in FC layer with 100 hidden unit (basis = 0)

```
FC layer = Wx = 100 x ( 500 x 500 x 3 ) = 100 x 750000 = 75M
```

on other hand:
input image of shape 500 x 500 x 3 will be after convolving a 5 * 5 kernel with zero padding, the stride of 1. and 2 filters

```
the new CNN layer = ((Hn + 2p - k )/s)+1,((Wn + 2p - k )/s)+1, Cn * filters num)
= 496 x 496 x 6
```

the number of parameters in a CONV layer is : ((shape of width of the filter * shape of height of the filter * number of filters in the previous layer+1)*number of filters)
1 for bias

```
number of parameters = (Fw * Fh * D + 1 ) * F  =  (5 * 5 * 3 + 1 )*2  = 152
```

**2. Explicit hierarchical representation of features.**
the best thing in CNN architecture is no need for feature extraction.

**3. Reduces overfitting.**
If the model is massively overfitting you can start adding dropout in small pieces. also, max-pooling reduce the overfitting too 
**4. Translation invariant.**
Invariance refers to the ability to remember an object as an object even though its object place changes. This is usually a positive thing because it maintains the object's identity, category,

"Note that [translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)) here has a specific meaning in vision, borrowed from geometry."

[image]
The same object in different locations.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please expand on your answer a little to show how it pertains to the question?

Comment: Thank you for expanding on your answer. While this elaboration is an improvement, it is mostly a sequence of claims without supporting reasoning. For instance, you say that a CNN is translation invariant, but you do not explain what properties of a CNN mean that it is translation invariant. Likewise for (2) and (3). For (1), you show that a FC layer of a certain size has some number of parameters, but don't even demonstrate that number is larger than a relevant CNN to use as a comparison.

Comment: It might be helpful to look at examples of highly-voted posts on our site. For instance, these https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks are the highly-voted questions about neural networks.